# DB populated ListView delete selected from DB on Button Click

Tags: android

Ok, I'm still kind of new to android and eclipse but the title pretty much says it all. I've got a ListView that I populated from rows in DB. I want to take the selected list view item and delete row from DB when button is clicked and then refresh ListView once this is done. So far my code populates the list, and I'm stuck there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class ViewListingsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ListView listview;
    Button button;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    String value;
    private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_ADDRESS = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String DB_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String DB_URL = "URL";
    final String dbTable = "Realtor_SMS_Table";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewlisting);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(ViewListingsActivity.this);
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(dbTable, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { DB_ADDRESS, DB_DESCRIPTION, DB_URL };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textlistaddress, R.id.textlistdescription,
                R.id.textlisturl };
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlist, cursor, from,
                to);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setChoiceMode(1);

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        db.delete(dbTable, "_id=" + value, null);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.d("wtf", "deleted: " + value);

    }

}
```

ok, here is my newly edited code:

```
public class ViewListingsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ListView listview;
    Button button;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    String value;
    OnItemClickListener listener;
    Cursor newcursor;
    String deleteinfo;

    private static final String TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_ADDRESS = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String DB_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    public static final String DB_URL = "URL";
    final String dbTable = "Realtor_SMS_Table";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewlisting);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(ViewListingsActivity.this);
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(dbTable, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] from = new String[] { DB_ADDRESS, DB_DESCRIPTION, DB_URL };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textlistaddress, R.id.textlistdescription,
                R.id.textlisturl };
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowlist, cursor, from,
                to);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setChoiceMode(1);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

    }
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    newcursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    deleteinfo = newcursor.getString(1);//getString(0);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        db.delete(dbTable, "_id=" + deleteinfo, null);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.d("wtf", "deleted: " + deleteinfo);

    }

}
```

my deleteinfo String keeps returning null, why is it not retrieving the proper column value?

Comment: Asking multiple questions in a single question format kind of defeats the question/answer schema doesn't it? Regardless, don't call getCursor() in the onItemClick - look more closely at my code in my edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are completely right. Anyway, I figured it out. You guys rock!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete, simply remove the rows from the database via normal querying. Afterwards, update your SimpleCursorAdapter by:

```
Cursor cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).getCursor();
cursor.requery();
```

**Note**
This must be done on a UI thread

**Edit**
Set an OnItemClickListener which provides you with a position parameter of the selected item. See [Adapter.onItemClickListener | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

This position can be used to grab a cursor pointing to the row:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) ((SimpleCursorAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
```

Comment: how do I know which ListView item (row in DB) the user selected?

Comment: That gives me the long ID for the position within... the list? the cursor?, I'm confused on how we relate that to the row in the database